# Proxy Settings for VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, proxy

I have VirtualBox installed and I want to configure it to connect to the Internet using my proxy so that it emulates my connectivity successfully to the VM.

However I could not find any options to set a proxy for VirtualBox so that my VMs cannot connect to the Internet.

Googled but not any relevant solutions appeared. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

There's no proxy setting in VirtualBox because proxy settings apply to specific application protocols (e.g., an http proxy), and VirtualBox provides generic internet connectivity.

First, make sure your virtual machine has a virtual network card that is connected to the internet. This is VirtualBox's job. Make sure your vm config includes a network adapter configured as NAT (this is the simplest choice if you just want programs running in the vm to connect to servers running outside the host machine). The OS inside the vm must use this adapter as the default route to the internet (with most OSes this will happen automatically; you may need to install a driver if you added the virtual network adapter after you installed the vm OS).

Then configure proxies in the software running inside the vm as you would if they were running directly on the host.

Comment: Actually there *is* a proxy setting, but it seems to only apply to checking for updates to VirtualBox.  (Perhaps it didn't exist when you wrote your answer, though.)

Answer (score 0):

Normally to connect to the internet from VM just the change the setting to automatic.

Even it's not working for some application the use the same proxy setting that your base OS is using.

Hope it will solve your problem